# Create repetitive task using Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I am using Task Scheduler library from here:
taskscheduler.codeplex.com

As per their examples, I am trying to create task with following behaviour:
Task should run at every 1 hour for all 12 months including all days of the month.

Following code is doing this except task does not get repeated every 1 hour. It run once and then it runs on next day.

```
                TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
                td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "sample task";

                // Create a trigger that will execute very 1 hour. 
                var trigger = new MonthlyTrigger();
                trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
                trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                trigger.Repetition.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
List<int> days = new List<int>();
                for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
                {
                    days.Add(i);
                }
                trigger.DaysOfMonth = days.ToArray();

                td.Triggers.Add(trigger);
                td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));
                // Register the task in the root folder
                ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"RemoteClient Task", td);
```

I have also tried TimeTrigger but that too does not repeat task. If I see the created task in Scheduled Task window, I see following:

[image: Task Scheduler actions]

If you see the red highlighted part, the task repetition is off. I need to enable it so my task can execute at every hour a day. Any help would be great in this direction.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe following line is culprit.

```
trigger.Repetition.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
```

You want to remove this line. I wrote following program and it works as expected.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get the service on the local machine
        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        {
            // Create a new task definition and assign properties
            TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
            td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

            // Add a trigger that, starting now, will fire every day
            // and repeat every 1 minute.
            var dt = new DailyTrigger();
            dt.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now;
            dt.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            td.Triggers.Add(dt);

            // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
            td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

            // Register the task in the root folder
            ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Test", td);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This is how above task looks in Task Scheduler UI:

[image]

Comment: I run the same code and it produce different task definition!. See the  screenshot here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/awq51jmdc5mxk4b/ts2.png

Comment: Thanks. It is working. I was using interval less than a 60 secs so it was not registering for every minute interval. Thanks for the help. :)